# Trigger "onkeyup" at jquery Dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, jquery-ui, combobox

I have a drodownlist that is supposed to fill with data from server, filtered by given characters. This is supposed to happen, when the user has typed at least 3 Characters. A function **SearchStartStation(value)** is called and then gets from the Server a list of items to fill the combobox.

My Question:  Where do I have to put onkeyup event and how does my call look like. I am confused how to get the inputvalue of the input field.

I used code from an Example (https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html) to get this partially done. The part where I call the function at onkeyup is the one that is not working yet. I have tried several ways but no success so far:

the part I am talking of is this:

```
this.input = $("<input>").appendTo(this.wrapper).val(value).attr("title", "").addClass("custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left").autocomplete({
    delay: 0,
    minLength: 3,
    source: $.proxy(this, "_source")
}).attr("change", function() {
    if (value != null) {
        SearchStartStation(value)
    }
}).attr("onkeyup", function() {
    if (value != null) {
        SearchStartStation(value)
    }
}).tooltip({
    classes: {
        "ui-tooltip": "ui-state-highlight"
    }
});
```

I have to add the event to the input field, but I am struggling with javascript/ jQuery functions/syntax, and nothing I've tried worked so far.

This is the javascript part for a combobox widget that is used throughout the whole page at several boxes. :

```
$.widget("ui.combobox", {
    _create: function() {
        this.wrapper = $("<span>").addClass("custom-combobox").insertAfter(this.element);
        this.element.hide();
        this._createAutocomplete();
        this._createShowAllButton();
    },
    _createAutocomplete: function() {
        var selected = this.element.children(":selected"),
            value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
        this.input = $("<input>").appendTo(this.wrapper).val(value).attr("title", "").addClass("custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left").autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 3,
            source: $.proxy(this, "_source")
        }).attr("change", function() {
            if (value != null) {
                SearchStartStation(value)
            }
        }).attr("onkeyup", function() {
            if (value != null) {
                SearchStartStation(value)
            }
        }).tooltip({
            classes: {
                "ui-tooltip": "ui-state-highlight"
            }
        });
        this._on(this.input, {
            autocompleteselect: function(event, ui) {
                ui.item.option.selected = true;
                this._trigger("select", event, {
                    item: ui.item.option
                });
            },
            autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
        });
    },
    _createShowAllButton: function() {
        var input = this.input,
            wasOpen = false;
        $("<a>").attr("tabIndex", -1).attr("title", "Show All Items").tooltip().appendTo(this.wrapper).button({
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
            },
            text: false
        }).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right").on("mousedown", function() {
            wasOpen = input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible");
        }).on("click", function() {
            input.trigger("focus");
            // Close if already visible
            if (wasOpen) {
                return;
            }
            // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
            input.autocomplete("search", "");
        });
    },
    _source: function(request, response) {
        var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
        response(this.element.children("option").map(function() {
            var text = $(this).text();
            if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text))) return {
                label: text,
                value: text,
                option: this
            };
        }));
    },
    _removeIfInvalid: function(event, ui) {
        // Selected an item, nothing to do
        if (ui.item) {
            return;
        }
        // Search for a match (case-insensitive)                
        var value = this.input.val(),
            valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
            valid = false;
        this.element.children("option").each(function() {
            if ($(this).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase) {
                this.selected = valid = true;
                return false;
            }
        });
        // Found a match, nothing to do
        if (valid) {
            return;
        }
        // Remove invalid value
        this.input.val("").attr("title", value + " didn't match any item").tooltip("open");
        this.element.val("");
        this._delay(function() {
            this.input.tooltip("close").attr("title", "");
        }, 2500);
        //this.input.autocomplete( ui.name ).term = "";
    },
    _destroy: function() {
        this.wrapper.remove();
        this.element.show();
    }
});
$("#MyList").combobox();
$("#toggle").on("click", function() {
    $("#MyList").toggle();
});
```

This is the mentioned function SearchStartStation to be called:

```
 function SearchStartStation(obj) {
     var input = obj.val;
     alert(input);
     //if (input.length > 2)
     //  alert(input);
     $.ajax({
         url: '@Url.Action("SelectStation", "DDSAboProductPage")',
         type: "GET",
         dataType: "JSON",
         data: {
             searchvalue: input
         },
         success: function(stations) {
             $("#MyList").html(""); // clear before appending new list 
             $.each(stations, function(i, station) {
                 $("#MyList").append($('<option></option>').val(station.Value).html(station.Text));
             });
         }
     });
 }
```

HTML part:

```
<select id="MyList" ></select>
```

Any help much appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I have tried this variant:

```
  this.input = $( "<input>" )
                .appendTo( this.wrapper )
                .val( value )
                .attr("title", "")                    
                .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
                .autocomplete({
                    delay: 0,
                    minLength: 3,
                    source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
                })
                .change(function () { if (value != null) { SearchStartStation(value) } })
                .onkeyup(function () { if (value != null) { SearchStartStation(value) } })
                .tooltip({
                    classes: {
                        "ui-tooltip": "ui-state-highlight"
                    }
                });
```

No success. I get an Javascript Error saying 
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).appendTo(...).val(...).attr(...).addClass(...).autocomplete(...).change(...).onkeyup is not a function

I also tried this one. It does not give me errors, but it is not working either. I am really confused where would be the right place to put the onkeyup-Event:

```
this._on(this.input, {
            onkeyup: function(event,ui){
                if (value != null) { SearchStartStation(value) } }})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The `.attr()` is to set a specific attribute for an element. I would advise using `.change()` and `.keyup()` instead to assign those event callbacks.

Comment: Yea well thats what I want! But I don't get the right place where to implement it obviously.
If I do this, I get errors and the events do not trigger: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).appendTo(...).val(...).attr(...).addClass(...).autocomplete(...).change(...).onkeyup is not a function

Comment: I have added the code to the post so you might take a look.

Comment: Yes, `.onkeyup()` is not a function. You can use `.keyup()` or `.on("keyup", function(){})` to assign the callback.

Comment: Thanks that helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this easier. Instead of long complicated code I used a simple Input field and used [JQuery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default) to get what I want.

But first, for those who fall into the same Javascript Jquery Confusiontrap like I did. The Event is keydown not onkeydown (thanks Twisty). The solution for my question was:

```
   this.input = $( "<input>" )
                .appendTo(this.wrapper)
                .on("keydown", function () {
                    SearchStartStation(value);
                })
                .val( value )
                .attr("title", "")
                .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
                .autocomplete({
                    delay: 0,
                    minLength: 3,
                    source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
                })
                .tooltip({
                    classes: {
                        "ui-tooltip": "ui-state-highlight"
                    }
                });
```

And here is how I finally did it:

```
<body>
        <script type="javascript">
        $(function(){
         $("#StationStart").autocomplete({
                             source: function (request, response) {
                                 var postData = {
                                     searchvalue: request.term
                                 };
                                 addAntiForgeryToken(postData);

                                $.ajax( {
                                    cache: false,
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    url: '@Url.Action("SelectStation", "DDSAboProductPage")',
                                    data: postData,
                                    dataType: 'json',

                                    success: function( data ) {
                                        response( data );
                                    }
                                } );
                            },
                            minLength: 3,
                            select: function( event, ui ) {
                                document.getElementById("SelectedStationStart").value= ui.item.value;
                                text = ui.item.value;
                                data = text.split(";");
                                ui.item.value = data[1];
                            }});

    )};

</script>
<input id="StartStation"><input id="SelectedStationStart" type="hidden" />
</body>
```